# Regarding my Javascript for auto displaying image URL - how to view image url w/o img extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption, oembed

I'm not even able to search for this answer because the terminology is foreign to me.  I'd be happy with just a starting point on what I need to research.  I'm not even sure what the definition is, would it be called encrypted url?

https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvMvl7LRHxafRFWLUS39Ku5FaSGEEbTuwiwkTZtxfEghLjScT1HsorllX2

That link is nothing but an image.

From looking at that url, you won't find any mention of jpg or png, any extension besides numbers.

Can those links be displayed through a script?

I currently run a phpbb based forum.  Many of our members are middle aged men who barely know how to download an app, let alone use bbcode buttons to embed media, so I've taken the task of automated scripts to make life easier for them (as well as myself so I don't have to explain it every time).

It might not seem like a big deal, for most of you, but for me, it was a monumental task since I had very little guidance on it, and the eureka moment when I figured it out was enough to really peak my interest in learning what else can be done with javascript.

My experience is limited to basic html and css, but I'm slowly getting my feet wet.  So anyway, here's what I have for embedding media through oembed, and then my own script for links that are identified as img-links through phpbb (assuming they parse those through extensions, and my code piggybacks off that).

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.postlink.img-link').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).html($('<img>').attr('src', href)).colorbox({photo: true, maxWidth: "800px", maxHeight: "800px"});
        });
})
```

So besides what I already have, is there a way to add a function for .postlink to identify an image url?

I've located this code online (can't take credit for it, I couldn't possibly devise something this complicated yet).  It seems this code does work for images which don't end with an img extension.  What would be the best way to implement the record (url, result) into my code which displays the img src?

```
    function testImage(url, callback, timeout) {
    timeout = timeout || 5000;
    var timedOut = false, timer;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = img.onabort = function() {
        if (!timedOut) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            callback(url, "error");
        }
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        if (!timedOut) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            callback(url, "success");
        }
    };
    img.src = url;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        timedOut = true;
        callback(url, "timeout");
    }, timeout); 
}


function record(url, result) {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<span class='" + result + "'>" + 
        result + ": " + url + "</span><br>";
}
```

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't really care how the URL for the image is put together. It does care however that your response has the correct "Content-Type" header, in this case "image/png". Not sure how you will do that in PHP but I imagine it isn't that hard. You also need to set the "Content-Length" with the byte size of the image.

Comment: I'm trying to pull the image from the url automatically, so it's not the browser, I need my script to be able to identify when the url is an image link and display the embedded image SRC just as it does with any link that ends in jpg/png/gif etc

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, you can access the response headers from javascript, look at http://help.dottoro.com/ljxsrgqe.php

Comment: OK, I've located a code, which may do what I'm seeking, can anyone identify the best way to use the recorded results to display the image src (like I have in my script so that it displays upon posting by a user)?